# TNS-12543: TNS:destination host unreachable

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I have a installed oracle 19c
but i am unable to login

Please refer the following screen shot

[image]

I am not unable to login
which user credential require to login

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the alert log to verify that the database is running. Can you show your environment settings for ORACLE_SID, ORACLE_HOME, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, TNS_ADMIN and PATH? Do you have a listener running? Can you also show the contents of your listener.ora, sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files? It could be that sqlplus can't find your database. Either using the listener or having ORACLE_SID set should get you to your database. You want to verify that the database and version of Sqlplus are both using the same Oracle Home.

Comment: I got the solution that i have to unlock the sys account first then i have to login via sys with new password.

Answer (score 1):

1) we have to login to the sqlplus in the command prompt and connect as sysdba

```
sql>connect /as sysdba;
```

2 ) alter the sys and unlock the account.

```
ALTER USER sys IDENTIFIED BY [newpassword] ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

3 ) you can login via following url :

```
https://localhost:5500/em
```

4 ) Enter the username as **sys** and new newpassword

5 ) you can able login as sys account and continue with your dba works